# Please help me converting this code to haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, ejs

**NOTE:** *I am trying to include the file upload system in my rails project. But I am getting issues with this EJS code. Please help me convert the below code into HAML code.*

```
<script id="b-file-ejs" type="text/ejs">
            <div id="file-<%=FileAPI.uid(file)%>" class="js-file b-file b-file_<%=file.type.split('/')[0]%>">
                <div class="js-left b-file__left">
                    <img src="<%=icon[file.type.split('/')[0]]||icon.def%>" width="32" height="32" style="margin: 2px 0 0 3px"/>
                </div>
                <div class="b-file__right">
                    <div><a class="js-name b-file__name"><%=file.name%></a></div>
                    <div class="js-info b-file__info">size: <%=(file.size/FileAPI.KB).toFixed(2)%> KB</div>
                    <div class="js-progress b-file__bar" style="display: none">
                        <div class="b-progress"><div class="js-bar b-progress__bar"></div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <i class="js-abort b-file__abort" title="abort">&times;</i>
            </div>
        </script>
```

Comment: http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Comment: @apneadiving its not working. It is asuming <%.. %> of ejs to <%.. %> of ruby. I need some other way to convert the code

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this tool, sometimes it works better:
http://www.htmltohaml.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following gem **haml_ejs**

check out this github link https://github.com/duncanbeevers/haml-ejs

Comment: Yes i am using this gem. But I don't know how to use the variable in ejs. I want to use the value in class and id




`code`<img src="<%=icon[file.type.split('/')[0]]||icon.def%>" width="32" height="32" style="margin: 2px 0 0 3px"/>

`code` <div id="file-<%=FileAPI.uid(file)%>" class="js-file b-file b-file_<%=file.type.split('/')[0]%>">

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below link convert HTML to HAML

> http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Comment: This link was already placed as a comment, and the OP has already said he wants an alternative method